# XML format for Deleting tally voucher

Tags: tally

Below is the xml with which I'm trying to delete voucher in tally:

```
<envelope>
  <header>
    <version>
     1
    </version>
    <tallyrequest>
     Import
    </tallyrequest>
    <type>
     Data
    </type>
    <id>
     Vouchers
    </id>
  </header>
  <desc>
   </desc>
  <data>
    <tallymessage>
      <voucher action="Delete" date="01-Jan-2019" tagname="Voucher Number" tagvalue="3" vchtype="Journal">
     </voucher>
    </tallymessage>
  </data>
</envelope>
```

But I'm getting this error on posting the xml although voucher number 3 with date 2019-01-01 is present in tally:

> ```
> <ENVELOPE>
>  <HEADER>
>   <VERSION>1</VERSION>
>   <STATUS>0</STATUS>
>  </HEADER>
>  <BODY>
>   <DATA>
> DESC not found  </DATA>
>  </BODY>
> </ENVELOPE>
> ```

Earlier the xml was working. For some reason it's not working now.

Answer (score 0):

the only change i made to your xml was changing `id` to `All Masters`

```
 <ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Import</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>Data</TYPE>
        <ID>All Masters</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
        </DESC>
        <DATA>
            <TALLYMESSAGE>
                <VOUCHER DATE="01-May-2019" TAGNAME = "Voucher Number" TAGVALUE="1234" VCHTYPE = "Sales" ACTION="Delete">
                    <NARRATION>Deleted by Mitalee
                    </NARRATION>
                </VOUCHER>
            </TALLYMESSAGE>
```

This is the response I got:

```
<ENVELOPE>
 <HEADER>
  <VERSION>1</VERSION>
  <STATUS>1</STATUS>
 </HEADER>
 <BODY>
  <DATA>
   <IMPORTRESULT>
    <CREATED>0</CREATED>
    <ALTERED>0</ALTERED>
    <DELETED>1</DELETED>
    <LASTVCHID>0</LASTVCHID>
    <LASTMID>0</LASTMID>
    <COMBINED>0</COMBINED>
    <IGNORED>0</IGNORED>
    <ERRORS>0</ERRORS>
    <CANCELLED>0</CANCELLED>
   </IMPORTRESULT>
  </DATA>
  <DESC>
   <CMPINFO>
    <COMPANY>0</COMPANY>.....
```

Couple of things you could do:

1. Check if the journal voucher actually exists. Try it for sales, purchase, etc. after verifying that the voucher is already present.
2. Check if educational mode is interfering with your xml request. You could have a friend run the xml on a licensed version of Tally.
3. Check the company and dates selected for this voucher number.